# SQL query to get latest user to update record

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a postgres database that contains an audit log table which holds a historical log of updates to documents. It contains which document was updated, which field was updated, which user made the change, and when the change was made. Some sample data looks like this:

```
doc_id  | user_id |      created_date      |    field    |  old_value    |  new_value   
--------+---------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+------------
 A      | 1       | 2018-07-30 15:43:44-05 | Title       |               | War and Piece
 A      | 2       | 2018-07-30 15:45:13-05 | Title       | War and Piece | War and Peas
 A      | 1       | 2018-07-30 16:05:59-05 | Title       | War and Peas  | War and Peace
 B      | 1       | 2018-07-30 15:43:44-05 | Description | test 1        | test 2
 B      | 2       | 2018-07-30 17:45:44-05 | Description | test 2        | test 3
```

You can see that the `Title` of document `A` was changed three times, first by user `1` then by user `2`, then again by user `1`.

Basically I need to know which user was the last one to update a field on a particular document. So for example, I need to know that User `1` was the last user to update the `Title` field on document `A`. I don't really care what time it happened, just the document, field, and user.

So sample output would be something like this:

```
doc_id  | field       | user_id
--------+-------------+---------
 A      | Title       | 1
 B      | Description | 2
```

Seems like it should be fairly straightforward query to write but I'm having some trouble with it. I would think that `group by` would be in order but the problem is that if I group by `doc_id` I lose the user data:

```
select doc_id, max(created_date)
from document_history
group by doc_id;

doc_id  | max           
--------+------------------------
B       | 2018-07-30 15:00:00-05
A       | 2018-07-30 16:00:00-05
```

I could join these results table back to the `document_history` table but I would need to do so based on the `doc_id` and timestamp which doesn't seem quite right. If two people editing a document at the exact same time I would get multiple rows back for that document and field. Maybe that's so unlikely I shouldn't worry about it, but still...

Any thoughts on a way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You want to filter the records, so think `where`, not `group by`:

```
select dh.*
from document_history
where dh.created_date = (select max(dh2.created_date) from document_history dh2 where dh2.doc_id = dh.doc_id);
```

In most databases, this will have better performance than a `group by`, if you have an index on `document_history(doc_id, created_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports window functions (e.g. PostgreSQL, SQL Server; aka analytic function in Oracle) you could do something like this (SQLFiddle with Postgres, other systems might differ slightly in the syntax):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/981af/4

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    doc_id, field, 
    first_value(user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY doc_id, field ORDER BY created_date DESC) as last_user
FROM get_last_updated
```

`first_value() OVER (... ORDER BY x DESC)` orders the window frames/partitions descending and then takes the first value which is your latest time stamp.

I added the `DISTINCT` to get your expected result. The window function just adds a new column to your `SELECT` result but within the same partition with the same value. If you do not need it, remove it and then you are able to work with the origin data plus the new won information.